# how to use spring.jersey.init.* in spring-boot?

Tags: jersey, spring-boot

How can I use spring-boot properties `spring.jersey.init.*` instead of

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.wadl.generatorConfig</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.examples.extendedwadl.SampleWadlGeneratorConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jersey)

In your configuration you should add the following:

```
spring.jersey.init.jersey.config.server.wadl.generatorConfig=org.glassfish.jersey.examples.extendedwadl.SampleWadlGeneratorConfig
```